# combobox selected value in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I am working on C#.net windows application. i am filling combobox on my winform by using follows.

```
cmbEMPType.DataSource = objEntityManager.EmployeeTypes();
cmbEMPType.DisplayMember = "EMPTypeName";
cmbEMPType.ValueMember = "EMPTypeId";
```

where `objEntityManager.EmployeeTypes();` in the manager method that gets the List from Linq to sql server. this is working fine.

but as i select the item form combo box, and clicked the button then in the button click event i am getting `cmbEMPType.SelectedValue` as `EmpType` return type rather than its Id. why should this? I don't want to create one more EmpType object. need simple selected value. also can not keep faith with SelectedIndex. it may varies for item each time.

```
**Edited**
      public List<EMPType> EmployeeTypes()
        {
            List<EMPType> EMPTypeList = null;
            try
            {
                if (CommonDataObject.dataContext.EMPAllTypes.Any())
                {
                    EMPTypeList = CommonDataObject.dataContext.EMPAllTypes.ToList();
                }
                return EMPTypeList;
            }
            catch
            {

                return EMPTypeList;
            }

        }
```

**Edited**

```
   private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

iEMPTypeId = cmbEMPType.SelectedValue;
}
```

here I must get inte. but asking of create the EMPType object.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using cmbEMPType.SelectedItem? This would normally get the selected object (EmpType), while cmbEMPType.SelectedValue would get the property specified in 'ValueMember'.

Comment: Yes,i am sure. I checked it thrice. but unfortunately there is SelectedValue. in fact you can also check its return type . it showing 'object'.

Comment: it will always return object because the value can be of any type so you need to cast it anyway. Please post more code as I asked in my other comment and we'll see what's going on.

Comment: what do you mean by "asking of create the EMPType object"? Do you get error? If so post here the full error message..

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This is the correct and expected behavior, you can't change it.</strike>

`SelectedValue` should return the type of the property, e.g. if EMPTypeId is integer it should return integer - please post more code so that we can try figuring out why you get different return value.

If by any chance you're using `SelectedItem` then have such code to get the ID:

```
 int selectedID = (cmbEMPType.SelectedItem as EmpType).EMPTypeId;
```

To handle cases when there's nothing selected:

```
object oSelectedEmp = cmbEMPType.SelectedItem;
int selectedID = oSelectedEmp == null ? -1 : (oSelectedEmp as EmpType).EMPTypeId;
```

Comment: Actually you are incorrect. SelectedValue should give the value of the field specified in ValueMember, NEVER the actual object. If no ValueMember is specified it gives a ToString() representation.

Comment: @Rewinder: so how can i figure out this issue. @Shadow Wizard : I think this is enough code i have provided.what you expect? in fact I want to get Selected Value as an integer. but it is giving me object type of EmpType. why should this ?

Comment: @Lal post the header of `objEntityManager.EmployeeTypes` method. Post the way you're reading the selected value.

Comment: @Lal not good.. you're calling `EmployeeTypes` but posted code for `EMPTypes` - please post code of the relevant method plus how you read the selected value i.e. your button click code.

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. please review now

Comment: @Lal OK what you posted so far doesn't shed any light. Waiting for the code of the button click plus also post the code where `EMPTypeId` property is declared in `EMPType` class. Also, is the code you posted originally your exact code?

Comment: @Lal OK, how can you tell `iEMPTypeId` is `EmpType` and not Integer? How do you check its type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the sequence of your code. Please remove the first line code to the last line. You will get an int value (`iEMPTypeId`) from `cmbEMPType.SelectedValue`.

```
cmbEMPType.DisplayMember = "EMPTypeName"; 
cmbEMPType.ValueMember = "EMPTypeId"; 
cmbEMPType.DataSource = objEntityManager.EmployeeTypes();

iEMPTypeId = cmbEMPType.SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to override the toString function in your EMPType class. As Edwin de Koning stated "If no ValueMember is specified it gives a ToString() representation."

Something like (I cant test it at the moment):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ID;
}
```

You can check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx