# Combo Box and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, combobox

I'm writing a simple first app using Winforms, C#, VS2010, and Entity Framework. Basically, I have a rich DB I'm tapping, and I've already set up the framework, successfully enough to populate a DataGridView control with a subset of the Work Order table.

Now, I want to place a combo box on the form ("cbProjectID") whose value is ProjectID and DisplayValue is ProjectNbr. I only want to put projects in the combo box list that are related to WorkOrders, and only unique ProjectIDs within that set (a project may have dozens of work orders....)

I'm assuming I need to generate a list from EF, using LINQ. I'm pretty new at LINQ, and I'm not figuring it out...Here's my code so far...

```
using System;
using CPASEntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrowseWorkOrders
{
    public partial class BrowseWOs : Form
    {
        public BrowseWOs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseWOs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = new CPASEntities();
            var query = context.tblWorkOrders.Where(c => c.ProjectID==8);
            tblWorkOrderBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();

        //  Now, I want to load up the Combo Box with all the projects in the Work Order Table

        }
    }
}
```

I've been through the net trying to find a method I understand, but I'm failing. Perhaps someone can help me out. Here's my Datasource (I assume I should NOT use tblProject, but instead use the tblProject inside tblWorkOrder in order to get my subset...)

[image: Entity Framework Datasource]

Any help and/or guidance would be appreciated.

---

Here's the code now...

```
namespace BrowseWorkOrders
{
    public partial class BrowseWOs : Form
    {
        public BrowseWOs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseWOs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Following loads up all Projects into the cbProjectID Combo Box

            var context = new CPASEntities();
            var PrID = context.qryProjectIDNbrDescs.ToList();
            cbProjectID.DataSource = PrID;
            cbProjectID.ValueMember = "ID";
            cbProjectID.DisplayMember = "ProjectNbr";
        }

        private void cbProjectID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = new CPASEntities();
            var query = context.tblWorkOrders.Where(c => c.ProjectID == (int)cbProjectID.SelectedValue).ToList();
            tblWorkOrderBindingSource.DataSource = query;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the mistake I made in this forum thread: 
[Stack Overflow Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992129/combobox-selected-value-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the tblProject on the top because the other is for a single WorkOrder only. However, you need to filter the list with those who have at least on WorkOrder:

```
var projects = context.tblProjects.Where(p => p.tblWorkOrders.Any()).ToArray();
cbProjectID.DataSource = projects;
cbProjectID.ValueMember = "ProjectID";
cbProjectID.DisplayMember = "ProjectNbr";
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was getting close to that last night after I posted (I worked on it for awhile) but one thing left...Orderby? What's the syntax.

Comment: Amiran, I want to order by WONbr. But, I also remembered a query in the db that has exactly the Project combo box detail I wanted, and with your advice, got it working. Thank you. Now, I'm stuck using the selected item as a filter for the dataviewgrid. dataviewgrid has a property called "Filter", but I can't seem to extract the chosen ID from the combobox to set the filter property. Oh, well, one step at a time -- just wish each step didn't take so long -- but I am learning. Thank you again Amiram.

Comment: Get the selected value from the `SelectedValue` property and filter your query, like: context.tblWorkOrders.Where(c => c.ProjectID==(int)cbProjectID.SelectedValue);

Comment: I have simplified things a bit now that I'm gaining more understanding. So, now, I'll set the datasource for the DataGridView only after the user has made a selection in the combo box, but Amiram, I'm still having issues with SelectedValue...

... It seems to fire many times on form load, perhaps with each new entry in the list?
... I used your statement above (copied/pasted), and I got a conversion failure. The datasource is an EF object, so the SelectedValue Property points to an object, not an integer. I tried to use the "ID" property of the object, but Intellisense had none of it.